# Pipe ReadableStream to Transform

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I have Node code that I honestly don't fully understand but AFAIK it streams and transforms the received data.

```
var download = got.stream(remoteURL, { isStream: true })

var resultTransform = new Transform({
        transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
            ..
}
return download.pipe(resultTransform, { end: true })
```

I want to do the same in the browser.

What I am trying is

```
var download = await fetch(remoteURL)

..

console.log(typeof(download.body)) 
// "ReadableStream {locked: false}"

return download.body.pipeThrough(resultTransform) 
// "Failed to execute 'pipeThrough' on 'ReadableStream': Failed to read the 'readable' property from 'ReadableWritablePair': Failed to convert value to 'ReadableStream'"
```

Along with every combination with `.body` and `.pipe`.

I'm sure I am overcomplicating things there, how do I pipe the stream into the transform?

Comment: What does `resultTransform` look like?